# ASP.net shorthand in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, response.write, shorthand

I am trying to do the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text="<%= Name %>" />
```

When I execute my page it gets output as <%= Name %> instead of actually doing a response.write.

I tried modifying it to use the <% Response.Write(Name) %> instead but it did the same thing, putting the text there instead.

I can do this just fine:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= Name %>" />
```

That will actually work. Why doesn't this work when I use the TextBox control? Is there another way I'm supposed to do this?

Comment: The better approach is really to use code-behind assignment of the value. Any reason you can't do that here?

txtName.Text = Name;

Comment: I have to set 100 different things. I don't feel that code-behind is the better approach. WHat I'm really using this for is to get a unique validation group name for a User Control that has a validation group by using Client ID.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case yeah - Town had the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use code behind:

`txtName.Text = Name;`

Or, add `Page.DataBind()` in your code behind and change the syntax of your control to:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text="<%# Name %>" />`

*Note the `#` rather than the `=`. `#` represents a data-binding expression*

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Used # and added a DataBind() call to my Page_PreRender event.

Answer (score 0):

Because the control is rendered differently than a literal. Use the codebehind to set the `Text` property.